# SonarQube analysis with sonar-maven-plugin failed on spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, sonarqube, maven-surefire-plugin

I run a spring boot application on version 1.5.11 and i want to analyze the code with sonar-maven-plugin 3.4.0.905. A jenkins pipeline script builds the application and runs the sonarqube analysis with the following commands:

```
mvn -e -f ${CONTEXT_PATH}/pom.xml install
```

and

```
mvn -e -f ${CONTEXT_PATH}/pom.xml org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar
```

This setup works. Now i updated the spring boot version to 2.0.1 but now the analyze process () failed with error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project XYZ: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project INM-Weather-Data-Service: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: String index out of range: -1
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.data.SurefireStaxHandler.getClassname(SurefireStaxHandler.java:68)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.data.SurefireStaxHandler.parseTestCase(SurefireStaxHandler.java:58)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.data.SurefireStaxHandler.stream(SurefireStaxHandler.java:50)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:63)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.StaxParser.parse(StaxParser.java:55)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireJavaParser.parseFiles(SurefireJavaParser.java:111)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireJavaParser.parseFiles(SurefireJavaParser.java:102)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireJavaParser.collect(SurefireJavaParser.java:67)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireSensor.collect(SurefireSensor.java:65)
    at org.sonar.plugins.surefire.SurefireSensor.execute(SurefireSensor.java:60)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
    ... 23 more
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

**Edit 1**

The error belongs to dynamic test cases. I have several test classes like this one:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class Test {

@TestFactory
public Iterable<DynamicTest> test1() {
    ...
    List<DynamicTest> dynamicTests = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    dynamicTests.add(DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Test A", () -> {
            ...
    }));
    ...
    return dynamicTests;
}
```

With the maven-surefire-plugin i exclude all these dynamic test classes and it works. But this is not a permanent solution. Does anybody have the same issue or got a solution?

**Edit 2**

This is the shortened output of one surefire xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd" name="Test" time="0.004" tests="186" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
  <properties>
    <property name="sun.desktop" value="windows"/>
    ...
  </properties>
  <testcase name="Test A(test1" classname=")" time="0"/>
  ...
</testsuite>
```

Comment: Please show the full error log and not only excerpts...

Comment: I added the the log and the origin of the error.

Comment: Please share the content of the surefire xml report corresponding to your test. It seems to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: I added a surefire xml file and I shortened the list of _properties_ and the other test cases. They all look nearly the same. If you need the whole file i can provide it, but it is very large.